# SDK that would support a tablet-friendly, web-based, e-Reader-style text reading product with DRM and reading stats

Tags: pdf, sdk

I'm looking for an SDK that would support a tablet-friendly, web-based, e-Reader-style text reading experience for users. The product needs to support DRM (keeping users from being able to easily pirate the text) as well as provide hooks for tracking reader activity (what portions of the text were read, etc.).

The exact format of the text can be simple. No photos, special fonts, etc. are required. PDFs, EUPBs, Word Documents, HTML files, would all be acceptable forms of storage as far as formatting requirements are concerned.

Both infinite scroll style (e.g. typical PDF readers) and single page style (e.g. kindle) would be acceptable.

So far I have found the following: Readium, READynamic (based on Adobe Mobile Reader Mobile SDK), and PDFTron. Are there others I'm missing?

Edit: Open to any programming language/environment. The reader itself needs to be web-based, though. The reader does not have to have the ability to edit documents.